# Is it possible to add all the others into a column in PIVOT of SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table Pet.Info like the following in SQL Server :

```
pet      age ...
--------------------
dog       4
cat       3
pig       2
dog       3
...
```

Now, I want to convert it into a table to calculate the average ages of dog and cat, and the average of all the others. Like the following:

```
dog    cat   others
-------------------------
3.5      3       2
```

Is it possible to do it with PIVOT?

Here is what I have get, but there seems no way to make it for the column of others

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Pet.Info) AS B
PIVOT (AVG(age) FOR pet IN ([dog],[cat])) AS C
```

Thanks for advises in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (  SELECT  CASE WHEN pet NOT IN ('dog','cat') THEN 'others' ELSE pet END pet, 
                age
        FROM Pet.Info) AS B
PIVOT (AVG(age) FOR pet IN ([dog],[cat],[others])) AS C
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I was thinking of doing the trick in PIVOT.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use pivot for this.

```
select avg(case when pet = 'dog' then age end) as dog,
       avg(case when pet = 'cat' then age end) as cat,
       avg(case when pet in ('dog', 'cat') then null else age end) as others
from pet.info
```

For the others, I set up the statement so NULLs are included with others.

Comment: Thanks, your way also work. But @Lamak's way is what I prefer.

Comment: @Bob . . . No problem.  The issue I have with pivot for this example is the case where you want to get the average age of *all* the pets as well as the average of non-overlapping groups.